# How can I fill a QComboBox with all fonts from QFontDatabase?

Tags: qt, qt5, qcombobox, qt6, qfont

I want to add all fonts from my pc to QComboBox, how can I do it?

I expect a combobox list which will include all fonts from my PC. As I think, it can be possible with *QFontDatabase*.

Comment: Would a [QFontComboBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfontcombobox.html) work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments to your question, `QFontComboBox` should be helpful.

But for some reason if you are not interested in that, you can do it in traditional way.

Get the font families as a string list using [QFontDatabase::families()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfontdatabase.html#families), and then fill the combobox:

```
comboBox->addItems(QFontDatabase::families());
```